# Exact word conflict word with dash

Tags: php, regex

Originally, I use was just word boundary for exact word match - https://regex101.com/r/M97FkV/4

**Update 1**:

1) Exact word match with punctuation inside word like `20-year-old`

- Search `year's`, only `year's` exact is match

-- Search `year` alone, will not match `year's`

- If I search `20-year-old`, exact `20-year-old` is match

-- Searching `20` or `year` or `old` will not match `20-year-old`

2) exact match word before or after punctuation

- If I search `old`, exact word or before or after punctuation `old` `.old` `old.` `-old` `old-` `_old` `old_`  `old'`  `'old` these will match.

-- `old` will not be match with word with punctuation in it `20-year-old`.

Our last Progress

https://regex101.com/r/M97FkV/15 - solve (2) but not (1)

https://regex101.com/r/M97FkV/16 - solve (1) but not (2)

Comment: Do we need to account for the possibility of multiple leading or trailing punctuation?  `word,'`?

Comment: It is hard for me to tell on my phone but i would guess it is a unicode single quote or curly single quote.  Copy the character and paste into a google search to be certain.   I'll add the unicode flag to my answer when I get to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including case-insensitivity and unicode curly single quotes...

Pattern: `/(?:^|\s)[-_,'’.]*\Kold(?=[-_,'’.]*(?:\s|$))/ui`

Replace: `young`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/M97FkV/20

This input: `old 20-year-old _old-maid _old- -old old-’’’ 'old' 20-year-old old’ ....old`

Will become: `young 20-year-old _old-maid _young- -young young-’’’ 'young' 20-year-old young’ ....young`

`(?:^|\s)` matches the start of the string or a white space character.

`[-_,'’.]*` matches zero or more of the characters in the character class (list)

`\K` restarts the fullstring match. This is done to avoid using a capture group and more importantly a "variable-width look-behind" which php doesn't allow.

`old` is the literal string that is being search for.  You can apply your variable in this position.

`(?=[-_,'’.]*(?:\s|$))` is a two-part look-ahead expression.  It matches zero or more of the characters in the character class (list) then requires either a white-space character or the end of the string.

All of this convolution is done to match a targeted substring that has optional leading and/or trailing punctuation, but beyond that NO non-white-space characters.

Comment: @kiki updated.  If this is completely resolved, you may grant the green tick.  If you would like further explanation/clarification or if anything isn't quite right, please leave me a comment.  (we should also delete our now-obsolete comments to tidy up the page)

Comment: The core of my answer remains the same.  Expand the character classes per your needs.  https://regex101.com/r/M97FkV/23 I'll leave it to you to ensure the punctuation lists are accurate for your project.

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa! Will continue exploring, be back to learn new things!